# Java8 Stream Reduce

Tags: java, stream, reduce

Can anyone please explain how the reduce() is working in this code !! I am unable to understand what it is doing and how the result is 45 !!

CODE :-

```
/*
<U> U = Stream<T>.reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Optional;

public class StreamDemo4
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
        System.out.println("List = "+myList);
        Stream<Integer> myStream = myList.parallelStream();
        System.out.print("Result = ");
        Integer i = myStream.reduce(1,(a,b) -> (a*b),(a,b) -> (a+b));
        System.out.println(i.intValue());
    }
}

OUTPUT :- 
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Result = 45
```

Thanks & Regards
Saswata Mandal

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad use of `reduce()`, since the combiner function is not compatible with the accumulator function.

In order for them to be compatible, they must satisfy:

> for all u and t, the following must hold:
>
> combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)

In your code this would require that:

```
u + (1 * t) == u * t
```

which is clearly not true.

In addition, you also violate the requirement that

> The identity value must be an identity for the combiner function.

`1` is not the identity for addition. `0` is.

As for the result you got:

`reduce()` is not constrained to be executed sequentially.

If the `accumulator` is only used to multiply the identity element by an element of the `Stream`, and the `combiner` is used to combine all the partial results, you'll get the sum of the elements instead of the product of the elements.

Of course, you cannot rely on a specific result when you abuse the `reduce()` method this way. Different implementation can yield different results.

If you want reduce to correctly compute a sum, it should be:

```
Integer i = myStream.reduce(0,(a,b) -> (a+b),(a,b) -> (a+b));
```

If you want reduce to correctly compute a product, it should be:

```
Integer i = myStream.reduce(1,(a,b) -> (a*b),(a,b) -> (a*b));
```